# Changing of button title in iOS with swift 3 not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I am trying to change the title of a button using `setTitle`

I am getting no errors and my `IBAction` is working but nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var hourTimerButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func hourTimerButton(_ sender: Any) {
        hourTimerButton.setTitle("test", for: [])
        print("button")
    }   

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        hourTimerButton.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
        hourTimerButton.setTitle("test", for: [])    
    }
}
```

Comment: Try by setting state of the button while changing title.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting button like this for normal state.

```
hourTimerButton.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your button(hourTimerButton) references are properly connected, I have debugged your code now, everything is working fine. Better you can change `sender` type as `UIButton` instead of `Any`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var hourTimerButton: UIButton!

  @IBAction func hourTimerButton(_ sender: UIBUtton) {
      sender.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
      print("button")
  }   

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      hourTimerButton.setTitle("test", for: .normal)   
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

Title1 and Title2 are two different titles for your `UIButton`:

Change `@IBAction func hourTimerButton(_ sender: Any)` to

```
@IBAction func hourTimerButton(_ sender: AnyObject)
```

and then do this:

```
if (sender.currentTitle == "Title1"){
                button.setTitle("Title2", for: .normal)
            }
```

Hope it works!